# Is there a generic approach to unshortening URLs without generating "hits"?

Tags: hyperlink, spam, url-shortener, bit.ly, phishing

I have been tasked with performing realtime and historical analysis of shortened links that users include in their messaging, comparing them against databases of known-malicious URLs (e.g. [Google Safe Browsing](https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/), [OpenPhish](https://openphish.com/)).

However, a core use-case for link shortening done by our user-base is the collection of "hit" data, reflecting whether their link was clicked, who clicked it, when, etc. This presents the problem that I need to "unshorten" URLs without actually accessing them directly.

Some providers, such as [bit.ly](https://dev.bitly.com/v4/#operation/expandBitlink), provide an API method to retrieve information about their shortened links. But, each API seems to be different, and often requires provider-specific API credentials.

Are there any popular libraries, services, or standardized approaches for dealing with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In which language do you want? Here is one for bitly v4 in php:

https://github.com/phplicengine/bitly